# Map route in webforms with url extension

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working on an old application where I need a webForm to read query strings and return an asset (an image in most cases).
My route looks like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Assets", "Assets/{moduleId}/{fileName}", "~/Assets.aspx");
```

My code to return an asset:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string moduleId = RouteData.Values["moduleId"] as string;
        string fileName = RouteData.Values["filename"] as string;
        Repo repo = new Repo();
        var fileBytes = repo.GetFileBytes(moduleId, fileName);
        var mimeType = repo.GetMimeType(moduleId, fileName);


            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        }
```

If I hardcode the filename in the method, it works ok. My problem is that whenever I add the extension to the filename, I get a 404. Example:

If I open in the browser `localhost/Assets/1/2` then moduleId is 1 and fileName is 2

If I open `localhost/Assets/1/2.jpg` I get a 404

How can I hit Assets.aspx when my filename has an extension?

I know that a url like `Assets.aspx?moduleId=1&fileName=2.jpg` would work, but I need it to in the form of `Assets/1/2.jpg`

Comment: IIS is looking at `Assets/1/2.jpg` as a url pointing to a file with jpg extension. Introduce some logic so that a trailing slash is added to such route  i..e Assets/1/2.jpg/ `.

Comment: Also, try switching moduleId and fileName locations in route, so its `Assets/filename/moduleId` which would make the IIS think that its not pointing to a file since it doesn't end with `.jpg`.

Comment: @sunli, cant do any of that. I solved it already. I modified the static files handler so it doesn't apply to anything under Assets url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the following to my web.config:

```
<add name="Assets" path="Assets/**/*" verb="GET" type="AssetsHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```